# Selecting label element on check of nested radio button

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What would be the correct CSS syntax to target the label wrapped around the input-field?

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input checked="checked" name="duration" type="radio" value="2" />
                2
    </label>
</div>
```

This is not working:

```
.radio input[type='radio']:checked label { outline: 1px solid gray; }
```

Comment: `input` is inside `label` in the HTML, but in the `CSS` it assumes they're sibling elements.

Comment: Simply `.radio label` would target the `<label>`, but I guess there is more to this than you're letting on? :)

Answer (score 7):

As CSS cannot select the text nodes, you will have to wrap the `2` using a `label` tag, and than you need to change your markup like below as CSS cannot select previous element.

```
<div class="radio">
    <input checked="checked" name="duration" type="radio" value="2" />
    <label>2</label>
</div>
```

And use adjacent selector like

```
.radio input[type='radio']:checked + label { 
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zE2NW/)

---

If you do not want to wrap the `2` in the `label` tag as I showed you previously than use `span` tag like

```
<div class="radio">
    <label>
        <input checked="checked" name="duration" type="radio" value="2" />
        <span>2</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And selector like

```
.radio input[type='radio']:checked + span { 
    outline: 1px solid gray;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/zE2NW/2/)